# Getting the App Ranking from Google PlayStore

Tags: php, android, google-play

How do I get the App rankings of the apps in the Google Playstore (https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free) ?

Is there any API that i can use like in iTunes where I can get the results in json form which I could subsequently parse and display?

Came across a website http://www.appannie.com/ that could display the app ranking. Any idea how it could be done?

I am writing an php script to query for the results. Currently using the following code, I could get for a single app details:

```
$ids = 'ids=com.instagram.android';

$opts = array('http' =>
array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $ids
)
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free', false,$context);

$convert = explode("\n", $result);
print_r($convert);
```

I am getting back the results in an array. Now how do I similarly get for the top free/grossing apps?

Answer (score 1):

**Unofficial API's:**

> Play Store API is an unofficial version of Google Play Store which
>   will let you pullup applications from google play store using18
>   different functions covering almost everything from google store.

https://code.google.com/p/google-playstore-api/

> Play Store API is an unofficial version of Google Play Store which
>   will let you pullup applications from google play store using18
>   different functions covering almost everything from google store.

https://github.com/thetutlage/Google-Play-Store-API

> you may have your own android app store.these simple classes are free
>   and help you to get all app data from google play such as
>   name,permissions,price,screenshots and etc.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/googleplaystore/

> Need to see up to date reviews, ratings and **rankings** for products on
>   the Google Play Store in each country? Here it is! An easy to use web
>   service that retrieves current application details from Google Play
>   Store. Just give it an application id, that

https://www.mashape.com/maxcanna/google-play-store (PAID)

**Official API**

Is intended to use only for applications that you "own".

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/libraries (click the "other languages" button).

Comment: I tried the first 3 links u gave, but it just returning null. Not sure, maybe it could have been outdated. Have u tried the other method I have posted above? Is it possible to get the ranks from it?